# where not dataype sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, int, where-clause

I'm trying to filter some data - I have a column which looks like it is mainly smallint/int. Is there anyway I can run a where statement to say where not int or where not small int??

Microsoft SQL Server manager.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  You can just look at the type of the column to see what its type is.  The type does not vary from row to row.

Comment: In SQL a column is only one datatype. You could easily filter on whether or not a number is higher or lower though.

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL server manager.

Comment: At a guess `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(smallint,YourColumn) IS NULL AND YourColumn IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Simply apply the min/max range of the data type, e.g.`where column between -32768 to 32767` for smallint

Comment: @Larnu that worked perfect, :) still new to this so grateful for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a where clause that can tell you if the column contain information that can't be converted to `int` or `smallint`, you can use `try_cast`:

```
SELECT *
FROM <TableName>
WHERE TRY_CAST(<ColumnName> AS Int) IS NULL
```

You can change the `int` to `smallint` to get values that can't be converted to `smallint` but might be convertible to `int`.

Don't forget to replace `<TableName>` and `<ColumnName>` to the names of the relevant table and column.

The `Try_Cast` built in function will return null if the value in `<ColumnName>` is null or if it can't be converted to `int` (and since all `smallint` values can also be converted to `int`, it also can't be converted to `smallint`).